# K-Means clustering on spark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I want to cluster 1 million list of strings(names) which is converted into a tf-idf matrix using frequency-inverse document frequency (tf-idf) vectoriser parameters with names /4 clusters on Spark ec2 instance with 8GB RAM and 64 GB memory.

```
 str_no_cluster=names/4
km = KMeans(n_clusters=str_no_cluster,n_init=5,max_iter=30,n_jobs=-1)
km.fit(tfidf_matrix)
clusters = km.labels_.tolist()
print(len(clusters))
frame = pd.DataFrame(names_dict,index = [clusters],columns=names_dict.keys())
print(frame)
```

when i run python Kmeans program its halt for 10 to 15 min then stops executing program.
Any ideas how to make it faster and how much RAM and memory requires?

Comment: Please provide us Spark logs and - if possible - web ui metrics

Comment: By the way, code snippet that you've provided only say that you're calculating centroids. You are not evaluating your results so nothing will be shown in console

Comment: not able to get spark logs but result processing done by clusters = km.labels_.tolist() print(len(clusters))
frame = pd.DataFrame(names_dict, index = [clusters], columns=names_dict.keys()) and its working for <30000 names data